# Laravel 8 Two Table Where Search

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My Code;

```
$posts=Term::where('user_id',$user_id)->where('status',1)->where('type','product')->with('preview','attributes','category','price','options','stock','affiliate')->withCount('reviews');

       if(!empty($request->term)){
            $data= $posts->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->term.'%');
       }
```

This my code searches for title from term table. But I want to search from another table without breaking the structure. So Example;

```
 if(!empty($request->term)){

    $data= $termTABLE->where('title','LIKE','%'.$request->term.'%');
    $data= $stockTABLE->where('code','LIKE','%'.$request->term.'%');
    
}
```

Since I don't know about Laravel, I couldn't explain it fully. I hope I get help. Thanks.

Good Luck

Comment: Can you clarify what you think `$termTABLE` and `$stockTABLE` are in this pseudocode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example is not like yours' but you can sort it out according to your need.

For example, if user has a company you can search in the company table like

```
          $user->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchPhrase . '%') //Searching in user table
                //Searching in user table
               ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchPhrase . '%')
                //Checking if company exist
               ->orWhereHas('company', function ($query) use ($searchPhrase) { 
                    //Searching in company table
                    $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchPhrase . '%'); 
               });
```

Comment: Searching with 2 different tables from a single search query. How can I do that?

Comment: If you have relation setup then above code is a single query.